# How to run pipeline from Jenkins to another adress

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I got a task to create a pipeline on Jenkins which make a pull and up -d on docker compose on another workspace, another server. Just Jenkins is on 172.16.0.x and i have to run this pipeline on another server 172.16.0.x. I heard something about change the header '-URL' where POST is going. Can u help me guys where i can change it or how i can solve that ? I'm looking for and can't find anything. :(
My pipeline:
`pipeline { agent any stages{ stage('Update_docker'){ steps{ bat "docker-compose pull" bat "docker-compose up -d" } } } }`

When i running that pinepline on localhost everything going success.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute commands on a different server, you need to first connect to it. For example, you can SSH into the remote machine and execute the commands there. You can use something like [SSH Step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/) for this.

```
def remote = [:]
    remote.name = 'test'
    remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
    remote.user = 'root'
    remote.password = 'password'
    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
    stage('Remote SSH') {
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "docker-compose up -d"
    }
```

Another option is to add the remote server as a Jenkins agent and execute the command on the remote Agent. For this you can change the agent directive `pipeline { agent {label: "server2" ......`

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you very much for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
    stage('Update_docker'){
                step{
                    def remote = [:]
                    remote.name = 'server2'
                    remote.host = '172.16.x.x:9001'
                    remote.user = 'ci'
                    remote.password = 'xxxxxxx'
                    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                    stage('Remote SSH') {
                    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "docker-compose up -d"
                     }
                    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should I put it in step like this?